# How is the "Active Installs" count/percentage in the Android "Developer Console" calculated?

Tags: android

The Android Market Developer Console shows two numbers for your submitted application; "total" and "active installs".  What exactly does the "active installs" number mean?  Is it affected by application upgrades?

For example:

1. 500 users install v1.0 of an app
2. v2.0 of the app is released and all 500 people upgrade via the Market.
3. Assume no one uninstalls.

Does that yield a "total" of 1000 because the APK was downloaded 1000 times...but an "Active Installs" of 500 (50%) because, in the end, only 500 people are running the app? Does an upgrade get counted as an uninstall followed by an install?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1 person installing your app = 1 download.  Upgrades do not add to this.

So lets say you have 500 users.  That's 500 downloads.  Number of upgrades has no effect on this number.

Now lets say 100 of those users uninstall your app from their phone.  Now you only have 400 (80%) active installs.

I think what a lot of people don't get is that your phone posts back to the Android Market when you do an uninstall.  This helps with metrics tracking and is also required in order for the paid app 24 hour trial period to work correctly.

Comment: Today active installs went down by 6. Daily device installs - uninstalls was 54 - 50 = +4. Daily user installs - uninstalls was 40 - 47 = -7. So while the user installs kind of would make sense to use for "active installs" aka "actual users", it is not accurate, so what is going on? Others guess about inactive devices, but nothing concrete. (So the question is closed but keeps showing a most likely outdated but at least incomplete "correct" answer. How is that supposed to be?)

Answer (score 1):

I think active install = number of individual users who used your app in the last xx month period.

My guess would be xx = 2 months.

Sarika

Answer (score 0):

I think, the official explanation is not correct, because the number of active installs of my first app varied over time (**up and down**) while the absolute number of installs stayed the same.

Therefore I believe that its like Sarika said: active installs = number of installs that are used regularly by there users.

So what does "regularly" mean?

After I uploaded my first App, it took around week, until the market calculated a percentage of active installs. Although there were downloads, the active installs % stayed by 0. So I think your app has to be available for at least for a week for the market to calculate this number (= xx in Sarikas equation).